# How to Clone Project on Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I am using Team Foundation Services which is free in Microsoft: [visualstudio.com](http://visualstudio.com)

Is there a way to clone a project? I am checking online and it seems I cannot find any valid resources on how to do it. If I will do it manually, I will have to duplicate my project on my local and re-upload it again to my online TFS which if there is a way to do it online instead?

Comment: What do you mean by a "project"? Are you talking about source code, or an Azure DevOps team project?

Comment: The whole project source code @DanielMann

Comment: What are you using for version control? Git or TFVC?

Comment: TFVC @DanielMann

Answer (score 0):

Map a workspace in the folder containing the code you want to check-in, then check it in.